# How do I restore a backup created by 'brew cask upgrade'?

Tags: backup, homebrew, vmware

I just upgraded VMware Fusion on my system:

```sh
brew cask upgrade vmware-fusion
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
vmware-fusion 10.1.3-9472307 -> 11.5.0-14634996
==> Upgrading vmware-fusion
...
==> Backing App 'VMware Fusion.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/vmware-fusion/10.1.3-9472307/VMware Fusion.app'.
...
```

Alas, I only now noticed that I lack a license to use the new version, so I'd like to restore the backup which was created in `/usr/local/Caskroom/vmware-fusion/10.1.3-9472307/VMware Fusion.app`. How do I do this?

I suppose I could uninstatll `vmware-fusion` and then manually copy-back the backup -- but that supposedly fails to restore all kinds of symlinks which Homebrew created in `/usr/local/bin`. Is there maybe something built into Homebrew?